# Adding Image in html without specific path?

Tags: html, css, image

Creating a report that converts from HTML to *.rtf / *.doc

```
<header>
    <img class="img" src="C:/Users/????/Desktop/Test/img/header.png" alt="img">
</header>
```

After download the *.rtf or *.doc file, the image is loaded from the path, but if the user for some reason has no internet he can`t use the document without the image header because it should be a logo.

Is there an alternative to `
Where I can actually keep the image to the html...something like an img to css converter or something?

Comment: You're looking for [the `data:` URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Comment: Also see [this](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/).

Answer (score 1):

You can add the image as base64 encoded string.
example. `<img src="data:your base64 encoded string here" />`

You can convert your images to base64 encoding at http://www.base64-image.de

Link also has examples of how to use base64 encoding in img tag

Comment: Just base64 encoded string wouldn't work, you must use [the `data:` URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Comment: Yes, correct it will have to be <img src="data:your base64 encoded string" />